# SmtpException: The operation has timed out

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I try to send mail using C# and yandex, but I get an error:

"SmtpException: The operation has timed out."

Here is my code:

```cs
public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage
    {
        From=new MailAddress("mymail@yandex.com", "Management",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8),
        Subject=subject,
        Body=htmlMessage,
        IsBodyHtml=true,
    };
    mail.To.Add(email);
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Host = "smtp.yandex.com",
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@yandex.com", "password"),
        Port = 465,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
               
     };
     smtp.Send(mail);
     return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I tried with different ports and hosts.But actually I get same error for all attempts.

Comment: Try it with a different provider.

Comment: I tried with Gmail as a provider.But I get other error message :IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.

Comment: Could you try the connection without ssl? Maybe a certificate is missing. Try tls.

Comment: I solved this problem using another provider as an email sender.Thanks your helps.